# Scan QR with codenameone close it and return to main form

Tags: android, codenameone

I integrated the last QR code scan library and tried to used it as described in the doc.

https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan

The library works fine and i used this code to start scanning the QR code of a vcard and i want after the QR code is scanned to return to the form but i see no method to destroy the instance.

```
public void scanUUID(){
CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {

    public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
        Preferences.set("uuid",contents);
        //here it should stop and return to form
        loadBrowserUrl();
    }

    public void scanCanceled() {
        Display.getInstance().exitApplication();
    }

    public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
        System.out.println("err " + message);
    }
});
```

But i am facing a problem after scanning the QR code how to close the Scanner and go back to the current form.

Comment: This is implicit. Once you scan or cancel you will receive an event and would be returned to the current form. You have a cancel button on the camera view (or can use the device back button if available).

Comment: It is not the case actually it stays on scanner. Do i have to call scan code after form show ? Can i call cancel programmatically ?

Comment: I'm guessing there's an exception in the app preventing you from getting back to the UI Try removing `loadBrowserUrl` and `exitApplication` and see what happens